# C: Queue ADT data not returning correctly

Tags: c, string, queue, void-pointers

I am running Xcode 4.4.1 for this program.

**Object:** 
Insert user-input string into queue by calling `enqueue` and take out inserted string by calling `dequeue`.

**Test input:**

aaa

**What's not working:**

On the line where I call `dequeue(queue, &name)`, I am expecting to get the dequeued value of aaa. However, I get a garbage or NULL value.

// prototype declarations

```
int    enqueue     ( QUEUE *queue, void * dataInPtr );  // returns success
int    dequeue     ( QUEUE *queue, void **dataOutPtr ); // returns success
bool processQueue(QUEUE *queue, bool flag);
```

// function definitions (only `processQueue` is shown)

```
bool processQueue(QUEUE *queue, bool flag) {
  char *name;
  char usInput[MAX_LENGTH_INPUT + 1];
  int success;

  if(ENQUEUE == flag) {
    do {
      printf("Enter 3 letters for name: ");
      fscanf(stdin, "%s", usInput);
    } while(!validateInputName(usInput));

    name = malloc(sizeof *name * 4);
    name = usInput;
    printf("usInput==\"%s\" and name==\"%s\"\n", usInput); // correctly shown   
    return enqueue(queue, name);
  } else { // DEQUEUE == flag
    if (!emptyQueue(queue)) {
      dequeue(queue, &name); // I assume I have problem here??
      printf("dequeued name == \"%s\"\n", name); // incorrectly shown. why???
    // TODO: free(name);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

// output:

```
usInput=="aaa" and name=="aaa"
dequeued name == "¿" // here, I am expecting aaa, not ¿
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `malloc(sizeof *name);` is equivalent to `malloc(1)`.

Comment: I just fixed it to `name = malloc(sizeof *name * 4);`. It still returns ¿ (incorrect value).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is the problem:

```
name = malloc(sizeof *name * 4);
name = usInput;
```

By resetting `name` to point to the temporary `usInput`, you're (a) leaking memory and (b) causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, should I use `malloc` at all? What is the workaround?

Comment: The fix would be to `strcpy(name,input);` or to omit the malloc() and just use `name=stdup(input);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because when probably `enqueue()` takes a pointer to a string and stores it in the queue. In the statement:

```
name = usInput;
```

you replace the pointer you pass to `enqueue()` with a pointer to the start of an automatic storage array; that is storage that is not valid after your function terminates, which is why you see garbage. Storing/using pointers to memory that has been deallocated invokes undefined behaviour.

You seem to be confused about dynamic memory allocation and string copying. Here's one way you can handle it:

```
/* First, allocate enough memory. Let's say 12 bytes is enough. */
name = malloc(12);
/* We'll need to copy our string to the memory we allocated and truncate it to 12 bytes */
if (snprintf(name, 12, "%s", usInput) < 0) {
    printf("Output error encountered by snprintf\n");
    return -1; /* error value */
}
/* Now enqueue NAME assuming that enqueue() does not copy it. */
return enqueue(queue, name);
```

Be careful to:

1. Always check for errors.
2. Always impose a maximum input size.
3. Do not leak memory - `free()` what you `malloc()`.